# Indirect dependency issue in Xamarin.Forms solution

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I'm working on a Xamarin.Forms solution which is composed by:

- A .NET Standard project as the code sharing project. This project uses a set of Nuget packages as dependency. For example: [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/).
- A Xamarin.Android project.
- A Xamarin.iOS project.
- A .NET Core project for unit test.

The Xamarin.Android, Xamarin.iOS and .NET Core projects have reference to the first. The unit test project works fine, but:

when I run the Xamarin.Android project I get:

> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2,2):
>   Error: Exception while loading assemblies:
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'RestSharp,
>   Version=106.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=598062e77f915f75'.
>   Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile? File name:
>   'RestSharp.dll'

and when I run the Xamarin.iOS project I get:

> /Users/brunoperes/projects/MyAppV2/iOS/MTOUCH: Error MT2002:
>   Failed to resolve "RestSharp.IRestResponse" reference from "RestSharp,
>   Version=106.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=598062e77f915f75"
>   (MT2002) (MyApp.iOS)

That is: both Android and iOS builds are falling because they can not find the 'RestSharp' dependency.

Searching the internet the only solution I found is adding a manual reference to these libraries in iOS and Android projects. But this seems to be a "workaround", since RestSharp is a dependency of my .NET Standard (code sharing) project, and not a Xamarin.Android or Xamarin.iOS dependency.

How should I solve this issue? Should I add the dependency manually in my Android and iOS projects? If so, why the unit test project works without this manual reference?

PS: I'm using Visual Studio for Mac.

Comment: I have the same problem but only with Android. This is so frustrating.

Comment: Hi. When you are using VS on a Windows, it automatically gives you the option to add a nugget package for all projects, but on Mac you will have to do it on your own every time. The VS for Mac does not bring that option.

Comment: Please share your `.csproj` file.